# Why is the application crashing when calling `call_pv()`?

Tags: perl, crash, perl-xs

We are calling a subroutine `process_input` with [`call_pv`](http://p3rl.org/call#call_pv) and this is being called from a process code which processes text input up to the size of 1 MB. The process does the following:

- it eats the mail from any maileater client
- creates a new ticket in the application
- and replies back if the mail size is > 1 MB

I had recently sent a file around 800 KB which is causing constant crash of the the process reaching till 2 GB and crashing. Here is the call:

```
Call_pv("process_input",G_EVAL|G_ARRAY);
```

Any ideas would be helpful. Is there any alternative to `call_pv`?

Additional details: the text that was sent in the email contains accented characters.

Comment: Provide the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The processes dies because it ran out of memory. A 32-bit process has a 4GB address space, but only 2GB of that is usable by the application in Windows (and IIRC, 3GB in linux).